# How to dynamically rotate image in custom style in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to make a custom Style in OpenLayers that replaces a path (Coordinate list) with an image at the end of the path pointing in the direction for the path (like the head of a snake). I am having trouble figuring out where/how to access the geometry to set the 'rotation' attribute in the Icon constructor. As geometry and renderer are the only options that allow for functions, I assume I will need to do my magic within a custom renderer. Are there default Icon render functions I could extend?

Here's my current code:

```
export class IconFrontPath extends Style {
  constructor(options: IFPOptions) {
    super(options);

    Style.call(this, {
      image: new Icon({
        src: options.url,
        rotation: ????
      }),
      geometry: this.geoFunction,
      zIndex: options.zIndex
    });
  }

  geoFunction: GeometryFunction = feature => {
    const coordinates = (feature.getGeometry() as LineString).getCoordinates();
    return new Point(coordinates[coordinates.length - 1]);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to do in a regular style function

```
var style = function(feature) {
  var stringCoords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  var coords = stringCoords.slice(-2);
  if (coords[1][0] == coords[0][0] && coords[1][1] == coords[0][1] && stringCoords.length > 2) {
    // useful for drawing
    coords = stringCoords.slice(-3, -1);
  }
  iconStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(coords[1]));
  iconStyle.getImage().setRotation(
      Math.atan2(coords[1][0] - coords[0][0], coords[1][1] - coords[0][1])
    );
  return [lineStyle, iconStyle];
};
```

Example where you can draw lines https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/ExaMmQK

Comment: Thank you! I am new to OpenLayers and didn't know about style functions.